# SurfaceView camera not respecting setCameraDisplayOrientation on some devices

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview

The camera on the surface view I implemented was rotated 90 degrees anti-clockwise at the start. I used the following code to make it erect.

```
 if (activity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation != Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
         camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
 }
```

This is working fine on most of the devices but some still have the same issue.
I've also tried the code given on the [android dev page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation(int)) but in vain.

How can this be rectified? Some of the devices still having this issue are `Moto G5` and `Honor 9N`

Comment: some devices require `setDisplayOrientation(270)` in such situation. But **Moto G5** seems to have some [related bug](https://www.google.com/search?q=moto+g5+camera+sideways), probably not on all devices.

Comment: I've tried all the angles ie. 90, 180, 270.  This seems to be on more devices too. Have added another device facing this issue in the question.